# How can I cancel changes applied to an html element when hovering ( or clicking) on that element, after the relevant code is runned and finished?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to understand the DOM manipulation through JS, As an example, I used a form.
Let's suppose I hover over an input field or even click, the background of the form will go dark( just an example).
How can I cancel this change ( so that the background ocne again becomes light-blue), once I hover out the input field or click outside the form?

here is the code I am using for this : https://codepen.io/abdou-web-dev/pen/QWMxwdB

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((inputt) => {
    inputt.addEventListener('click', funct3);

    function funct3(e2) {
        myform.style.backgroundColor = "black"
    };
});
```

any help will be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: You can use `mouseleave`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseleave_event

Comment: thanks a lot , it worked. here is the code I added : document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((inputt) => {
    inputt.addEventListener('mouseleave', funct3);

    function funct3(e2) {
        myform.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.281)"
    };
});

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'blur' event listener for this.

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((inputt) => {
    inputt.addEventListener('blur', funct3);

    function funct3(e2) {
        myform.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    };
});
```

The blur event occurs when a DOM element loses its focus.

You can even implement this with pure css.

Use the :hover pseudo-class or :focus pseudo-class and you can write your color changes there

Comment: man, I am changing the background of the form, not the background of the input, when I am hovering out, I might even want to change the bg of the body of the wrapping container...
the CSS :hover pseudo-class does not change other elements...
I am asking for JS; anyway , I found the solution

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to scandav, I found the solution , which is :

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((inputt) => {
    inputt.addEventListener('mouseleave', funct3);
    function funct3(e2) {
        myform.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(135, 206, 250, 0.281)"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to implement this (if you're going for hover effects) would be to use mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Like this...

```
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach((inputt) => {
    inputt.addEventListener('mouseenter', funct3);
    inputt.addEventListener('mouseleave', funct4);

    function funct3(e2) {
        myform.style.backgroundColor = "black"
    };
    function funct4(e2) {
        myform.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue"
    };
});
```

Comment: yeah man thanks ,can you tell me all the events available for the mouse ?

Comment: yeah sure.. https://dzone.com/articles/all-mouse-events-javascript <-- you can visit this site for all event for the mouse in javascript

Answer (score 0):

SetTimeout solved this :

```
myform.addEventListener('mouseover', funct1);
function funct1(e) {
head1.style.color = "blue";
head1.style.transform = "scale(1.2)"
head1.style.transition = "all 4s"
const h = document.createElement("h3");
const word = document.createTextNode("pleease!");
h.appendChild(word);

setTimeout(() => {
    head1.style.color = "";
    head1.style.transform = ""
}, 1000);
```

};

Comment: I have another question related to this : Suppose I want the background of the form to become black only for a certain amount of time, like 4 or 5 s; and after that, I want it to get back to normal (light blue), whether or not I leave the input field with the cursor of the mouse. how can I do this with JS?